# How do I add a second condition to current exists function in a CubeMember function to return the ID field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, olap-cube, cubefunctions

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to apply two conditions to an Excel 365 CubeMember function.

I currently have an old query that was poorly written and fails when when there are two sub account names that are the same.  I would like to add the parent account ID to the condition as well as the sub account name and return the sub account ID.

The parent accent lives in the ACCOUNT table with ACCOUNT HCC ID being the parent account ID.
B9 holds the sub account name

Current Code:

=IFERROR(CubeMember("CubeName","exists([Sub Account].[SUB ACCOUNT HCC ID].Children,[SUB ACCOUNT].SUB ACCOUNT NAME].["&$B9&"])","")

Comment: Would something like this  help? CUBEMEMBER("CorrelationCube",{"[Curve].[Curve Name].[Brent]","[Terms].[Term Name].[M+1]"})

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother-mso_2010/cubemember-multiple-filters-set-dynamically/2f9ad8be-1d18-4c76-89a5-32348eea7ef3

Comment: helloooo?  _______